# Problemas com senha Bcrypt

Tags: php, criptografia

No meu script eu utilizo a função bcrypt(através de uma classe), e estou com o seguinte problema:
Na hora que eu realizo as últimas consultas antes do login eu preciso fazer a consulta onde o email e senha criptografada são iguais ao email e senha do banco, mas como eu faço isso? Uma vez que o bcrypt utiliza um salt e gera valores randomicos toda vez que uma senha é criptografada. 
Traduzindo para MD5 seria mais ou menos assim o que eu queria:

```
<?php 
 $email = "teste@teste.com";
 $senha = "123";
 $senhaCript= md5($senha);
 $select = (Select ... WHERE email = $email && senha = $senhaCript);
```

E assim em diante, mas o problema é que se eu criptografo a senha com blowfish, ele entra no bloco if do senha inválida. 

**Detalhe: para cadastrar o usuário eu utilizo a mesma classe

Código da página de checagem de login:

```
<?php
session_start();

define('TENTATIVA_LOGIN', 5); 
define('TEMPO_BLOQUEIO', 30); 

require ("bcrypt.php");
require ("conexao.php");
$pdo = conectar();

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "http://localhost:8080/Metta/html/login.php"):
    echo "<script>alert('A requisição não foi feita pelo formulário de login');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.history.back();</script>"; 
    exit();
endif;

$email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email_form']));
$senha = trim(strip_tags($_POST['senha_form']));
$hashForm = Bcrypt::hash($senha);

$buscaSQL = $pdo->prepare('SELECT email FROM tbl_usuario WHERE email = ?');
$buscaSQL->execute(array($email));

if($buscaSQL->rowCount() <= 0):
    echo "<script>alert('O email digitado: ".$email. " não foi encontrado!');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.history.back();</script>"; 
    exit;
    endif;

$searchSQL = $pdo->prepare('SELECT email,senha FROM tbl_usuario WHERE email = ? && senha = ?');
$searchSQL->execute(array($email, $hashForm));
$linha = $searchSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$hashDB = $linha['senha'];

if(!(Bcrypt::check($hashForm, $hashDB))):
    echo "<script>alert('Senha inválida para este usuário!');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.history.back();</script>";
    exit;
else:
   echo "<script>alert('Login realizado com sucesso!');</script>";
   //echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php'();</script>";

$resultSQL = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE email = ? && senha = ?");
$resultSQL->execute(array($email , $senha));
$row = $resultSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$_SESSION['login'] = $email;
$_SESSION['cod_usuario'] = $row['cod_usuario'];
$_SESSION['nome'] = $row['nome'];
$_SESSION['tipo'] = $row['tipo'];
$_SESSION['permissoes'] = $row['permissoes'];
$_SESSION['img'] = $row['img'];
$_SESSION['link_box'] = $row['link_box'];
$_SESSION['fk_empresa'] = $row['fk_empresa'];
$_SESSION["logado"] = TRUE;
endif;
?>
```

Código da Classe:

```
<?php
class Bcrypt {

/**
 * Default salt prefix
 * 
 * @see http://www.php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php
 * 
 * @var string
 */
    protected static $_saltPrefix = '2a';

/**
 * Default hashing cost (4-31)
 * 
 * @var integer
 */
    protected static $_defaultCost = 10;

/**
 * Salt limit length
 * 
 * @var integer
 */
    protected static $_saltLength = 22;

/**
 * Hash a string
 * 
 * @param  string  $string The string
 * @param  integer $cost   The hashing cost
 * 
 * @see    http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php
 * 
 * @return string
 */
    public static function hash($string, $cost = null) {
        if (empty($cost)) {
            $cost = self::$_defaultCost;
        }

        // Salt
        $salt = self::generateRandomSalt();

        // Hash string
        $hashString = self::__generateHashString((int)$cost, $salt);

        return crypt($string, $hashString);
    }

/**
 * Check a hashed string
 * 
 * @param  string $string The string
 * @param  string $hash   The hash
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
    public static function check($string, $hash) {
        return (crypt($string, $hash) === $hash);
    }

/**
 * Generate a random base64 encoded salt
 * 
 * @return string
 */
    public static function generateRandomSalt() {
        // Salt seed
        $seed = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);

        // Generate salt
        $salt = base64_encode($seed);
        $salt = str_replace('+', '.', $salt);

        return substr($salt, 0, self::$_saltLength);
    }

/**
 * Build a hash string for crypt()
 * 
 * @param  integer $cost The hashing cost
 * @param  string $salt  The salt
 * 
 * @return string
 */
    private static function __generateHashString($cost, $salt) {
        return sprintf('$%s$%02d$%s$', self::$_saltPrefix, $cost, $salt);
    }

}
```

Comment: Saul, as senhas que estão salvas no banco de dados, já foram criptografadas com blowfish?

Comment: O PHP já tem o `password_hash` que usa o BCrypt (e futuramente o Argon2) porque não utiliza ela?

Comment: Acho que o erro é `senha = ?`, o BCrypt vai usar outro salt, assim gerando outra "hash", não a mesma cadastrada.

Comment: @Inkeliz você poderia dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao registrar uma entrada (usuário) você encripta... o que será armazenado um hash.

Ao realizar a verificação você deve encriptar novamente a entrada fornecida o que ira gerar um novo valor (diferente do antigo) o que acontece é que esta classe permite verificar a hash... mesmo que o resultado seja diferente a hash é igual se os valores fornecidos forem iguais.

**exemplo.php**

```
// encriptar
$pwd =  '123456';
$mail = 'mymail@gmail.com';

require 'Bcrypt.php';

$Bcrypt = new Bcript();
echo $Bcrypt->hash( $pwd.$mail, "04" );

// output: $2a$04$MTM3NzcyMDM3MTU4YmRiMOyxZ4rQqGaCJnk1k4OYaIfebUy4C1j/m

/** Ao realizar novamente a mesma operação com mesmos dados o resultado será diferente:
    echo $Bcrypt->hash( $pwd.$mail, "04");
    // output: $2a$04$NDc2Njc2NjUyNThiZGIxN.ujzdaxw57G.aznwtd/CHGoROfdp8GrO
*/
```

Ou seja você salva no banco de dados más não deve fazer uma verificação **bruta** deves utilizar a classe para verificar se a nova `hash` gerada com os mesmos valores é compatível com a `hash` antiga (armazenada no banco de dados).

**exemplo2.php**

```
require 'Bcrypt.php';

$Bcrypt = new Bcript();

// hash armazenada no banco de dados
$dbPwd = "$2a$04$MTM3NzcyMDM3MTU4YmRiMOyxZ4rQqGaCJnk1k4OYaIfebUy4C1j/m"

// input do usuário
$pwd = "123456";
$mail = "mymail@gmail.com";

// verificar

if ( !$Bcrypt->check($pwd.$mail, $dbPwd) ) {
     // false
} else {
     // true
}
```

A lógica nestes exemplos deve ser observada. Deve-se ter algum indice para buscar no banco de dados... normalmente o e-mail do usuário para caso esteja cadastrado retornar a `hash` armazenada e comparar usando a classe.

Acho que seja isto

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante!

Comment: Perdi a tarde fazendo isso

Answer (score 2):

Nas versões recentes do PHP existe o `password_hash` e o `password_verify` que é mais seguro que esta classe e ambos usam BCrypt.

Para usar o `password_hash` basta fazer isso:

```
$email = 'email@provedor.com';
$senha = '123456';

$senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, [cost => 12]);
```

Salva o `$senha` e `$email` no banco de dados. O `salt` deve ser gerado a cada vez e não deve ser constante, muito menos gerado utilizando `mt_rand` como é feito na classe acima, o próprio PHP diz ["This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes."](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php), *não é invenção minha*.

---

Depois disso para fazer o *login* utilize o `password_verify` ele é protegido contra ataques *side-channel* como o *timing attacks*, ao contrário do `crypt($string, $hash) === $hash`:

```
$email = 'email@provedor.com';
$senha = '123456';

$pega_usuario = 'SELECT senha FROM tabela WHERE email = ?';
//...
$hash_do_usuario_do_banco = $pega_usuario['senha'];

if(password_verify($senha, $hash_do_usuario_do_banco)){
  // Senha válida
}else{
  // Senha inválida
}
```

---

Se quiser utilizar a classe recomendo fazer algumas alterações para maior segurança, *estas são as que detectei*:

- Troque o `uniqid(mt_rand(), true)` para `random_bytes()`, o `mt_rand` não é bom para este proposito.
- Remover o `base64_encode` é vulnerável a ataques em *side-channels*, "content-leaking", o `str_replace` *deve* ser também, *melhor remover*, o **`bin2hex()` ainda é vulnerável**.
- Troque a comparação `crypt($string, $hash) === $hash` pelo mesmo motivo acima e em seu lugar utilize `hash_equals()`.

Desta forma ficaria assim as modificações, compatível com o PHP 7:

```
class Bcrypt {

/**
 * Default salt prefix
 * 
 * @see http://www.php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php
 * 
 * @var string
 */
    protected static $_saltPrefix = '2a';

/**
 * Default hashing cost (4-31)
 * 
 * @var integer
 */
    protected static $_defaultCost = 10;

/**
 * Salt limit length
 * 
 * @var integer
 */
    protected static $_saltLength = 22;

/**
 * Hash a string
 * 
 * @param  string  $string The string
 * @param  integer $cost   The hashing cost
 * 
 * @see    http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php
 * 
 * @return string
 */
    public static function hash($string, $cost = null) {
        if (empty($cost)) {
            $cost = self::$_defaultCost;
        }

        // Salt
        $salt = self::generateRandomSalt();

        // Hash string
        $hashString = self::__generateHashString((int)$cost, $salt);

        return crypt($string, $hashString);
    }

/**
 * Check a hashed string
 * 
 * @param  string $string The string
 * @param  string $hash   The hash
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
    public static function check($string, $hash) {
        return hash_equals(crypt($string, $hash), $hash);
    }

/**
 * Generate a random base64 encoded salt
 * 
 * @return string
 */
    public static function generateRandomSalt() {

        $seed = random_bytes(self::$_saltLength);

        return bin2hex($seed);
    }

/**
 * Build a hash string for crypt()
 * 
 * @param  integer $cost The hashing cost
 * @param  string $salt  The salt
 * 
 * @return string
 */
    private static function __generateHashString($cost, $salt) {
        return sprintf('$%s$%02d$%s$', self::$_saltPrefix, $cost, $salt);
    }

}
```

> **Pode haver outros problemas!**

Comment: Muito obrigado vou seguir o seu conselho e do php e utilizar o password verify